# How can I start some work as soon as a stored procedure that is called from a Spring Services finishes its work?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, stored-procedures, transactions

Does the code from the stored procedure (from a mysql db) execute asynchronous from the code I execute in a spring service?

Will the the code from my Spring Service resume only when the queries of the Stored Procedure are finished executing?

If the code executes asynchrounously, how can I force the code from the Spring Service to execute only after the code from the stored procedure is  is done?

Comment: what happens when you test it?

Comment: All depends on how you have implemented it. Without any details regarding your implementation, it's not possible to give answers with any kind of precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously yes. When you call a stored procedure from service then the rest of the execution will only start after the stored procedure is executed.